# the codemirror6 did not show hint after add the autocompletion

Tags: codemirror-6

I am using codemirror6 to edit the tex source file, after added the autocomplete extension like this:

```
import { autocompletion } from "@codemirror/autocomplete";
import { javascript } from "@codemirror/lang-javascript";
const state = EditorState.create({
        doc: ytext.toString(),
        extensions: [
            basicSetup,
            yCollab(ytext, wsProvider.awareness, { undoManager }),
            extensions,
            solarizedLight,
            autocompletion(),
            javascript(),
        ]
    });
```

the editor did not show hint when user input content. Am I missing something? I have read the official document https://codemirror.net/examples/autocompletion/ and told that Some language packages come with support for proper autocompletion built in. why did not seem the build in language autocompletion?